# got some errors when using "requesLocationUpdates()"

Tags: java, android, android-location, locationmanager, locationlistener

I have an app which shows users current coordinates and update it as every 5 meters.
but i have problem in the line which i call for "requestLocationUpdates" which is in this line:

```
 Location location1 = locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(GpsProvider, 0, MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, mylocationListener);
```

.

if i place Context as last parameter i will get an error which tells(note that "GpsTracker" is my Main Activity) :

```
"Cannot resolve method 'requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String, int, long, com.project.gpstrackerr.GpsTracker)'"
```

and if i place my locationlistener i will get an error which tells:

```
Incompatible types.
Required:android.location.Location
Found:void
```

here is my Full code of my GpsTracker Activity(which is my Main Activity)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class GpsTracker extends Activity
{
    public static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1;
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 20;
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false, isNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean isGPSEnabled2 = false, isNetworkEnabled2 = false;

    DatabaseTable cn;
    DatabaseManager db = new DatabaseManager(this);
    HttpClass JSONSaver = new HttpClass();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    Context context = GpsTracker.this;
    LocationManager locationManager, locationManagerCHECK;
    TextView ET_Coordinates, ET_NU;
    ListView listView;

    //for Coordinates details in Location Listener
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    String Date;
    //for Getting Coordinates details
    String strLat, strLong, strDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Show Last Known Location
        ShowLastKnownLocation();

        String NetworkProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        String GpsProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled2 = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled2 = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    }
    public LocationListener mylocationListener = new LocationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {

            Date date = new Date();
            Date = dateFormat.format(date);
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
            Toast.makeText(GpsTracker.this, "Provide Status Changed" + "\n"
                            + "Provider: " + provider + "\n"
                            + "Status: " + status + "\n"
                            + "Extras: " + extras + ".",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Toast.makeText(GpsTracker.this,
                    "Provider Turned ON!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Toast.makeText(GpsTracker.this,
                    "Provider is OFF!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    protected void showUpdatedLocation(boolean checkGPSEnabled, boolean checkNetworkEnabled, String NetworkProvider, String GpsProvider, LocationManager locationManager)
    {
        if (checkGPSEnabled)
        {
           //I have problem in this Line
            Location location1 = locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(GpsProvider, 0, MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, mylocationListener);

            if (location1 != null)
            {
                Date = dateFormat.format(date);
                latitude = location1.getLatitude();
                longitude = location1.getLongitude();

                db.addContact(new DatabaseTable(Date, latitude, longitude));
                JSONSaver.writeJSON(Date, latitude, longitude);
                showOnTextView(Date, latitude, longitude);
            }
        }
        else if (isNetworkEnabled2)
        {
            Location location1 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (location1 != null)
            {
                //I have problem in this Line
            Location location1 = locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(NetworkProvider, 0, MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, mylocationListener);

                Date = dateFormat.format(date);
                latitude = location1.getLatitude();
                longitude = location1.getLongitude();

                db.addContact(new DatabaseTable(Date, latitude, longitude));
                JSONSaver.writeJSON(Date, latitude, longitude);
                showOnTextView(Date, latitude, longitude);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know where is my problem and how can i solve it and which of them(Context or LocationListener) is better to be used for doing my job.

It's my first time that i ask a question in Stackoverflow so if explanations have some lacks or i was not very clear or any other problems,
feel free to ask for more information in comments I will try to be as much as clear i can.
and beside of that I'm Kind of New to Programming so if you find something Stupid in my codes Don't get Surprised :D.
Thanks for Further Helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all people who helped me! the problem was for the package i used that was:

```
import android.location.LocationListener;
```

I used next package instead of first package:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
```

using this package in @chiru 's script will work fine for me!

Thanks A Lot Again!

Answer (score 1):

Error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to Location. This the actuall error you should get when you run above code.

You are expecting location in the place where void is returning. requestLocationUpdates uses LocationListener object of LocationManager class to receive periodic updates about the geoposition.

```
//Implement LocationListener to your class and implement callback methods 
//use the below code at onCreate
//[Changes starts here]
// Get the location manager
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
// Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use default
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

// Initialize the location fields
if (location != null) {
    System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
    onLocationChanged(location);
}
//[Changes ends here]

//onLocationChanged method you'll get the updated locatioin
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
}

/* Request updates at startup */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}

/* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
```

Source: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Comment: I have tested a locationListener but it said it returns void. I really doesn't have no Idea how to solve it. if you can please give a snippet of code ! :(

Comment: thanks a lot it really helped me in my code and I have solved the problem but any way thanks REALLY a lot(sorry i can not vote up your answer my reputation wouldn't let me to do that)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error at this line of code :

```
...requestLocationUpdates(NetworkProvider, 0, MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, mylocationListener);
```

The method `requestLocationUpdates` has the parameters: `String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener`

This is what you put in:

```
NetworkProvider provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener
```

The only reason I'd see of the compiler giving an error is because `NetworkProvider` isn't a String. Otherwise, your `locationManager` simply doesn't have `requestLocationUpdates(..)`.

Comment: It says "`//I have problem in this Line`"